# Kill WIndows Process for particular users through Schedule task

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

We are trying to implement a schedule task via GPO to kill the processes for some users.
I am trying to run the below powershell script via cmd.exe and getting the below error. Could you please help me on this?

```
PowerShell.exe -command "& $users=@('ADM-Suman');$processes=Get-WmiObject WIn32_Process;Foreach($Proc in $processes) {If(($Proc.GetOwner().User) -in $Users){$Proc.Terminate()}}"
```

I am getting the below error.

```
You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.
At line:1 char:122
+ & $users=@('ADM-Suman');$processes=Get-WmiObject WIn32_Process;Foreach($Proc
in $processes) {If(($Proc.GetOwner().User) - <<<< in $Users){$Proc.Terminate()}
}
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx
ception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedValueExpression


C:\Users\ADM-SUman>
```

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell 2.0 does not have the `-in` containment operator. It was introduced in PowerShell 3.0 as you can read in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7). You can use the `-contains` containment operator instead, you just have to switch the sides:

```
$Users -contains $Proc.GetOwner().User
```